# WordPress JQuery.. WordPress is ignoring my code

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Apologies if this is a stupid question but how do I get WordPress to actually look at my code! It is ignoring it completely and just obeying the HTML.

It is as if the jQuery is not there at all. I'm sure I've made some errors in the jQuery code but I have no real idea as I can't even test it.

I have read the '$' needs to be changed to `jQuery` which I have done. I have installed _js in the public_html file and also added the jQuery text there in case that helped at all.

I also added the following to `functions.php` on the advice of others here:

```
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() .'/_js/meet-the-team.js', array('jquery'));
       }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

This the code that is being ignored:

```
<script src="../_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('#gallery img').each(function(i) {
    var imgFile = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    var preloadImage = new Image(); =
    var imgExt = /(\.\w{3,4}$)/;
    preloadImage.src = imgFile.replace(imgExt, '_h$1');
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(this).hover(
      function() {
        jQuery(this).attr('src', preloadImage.src);
      },
      function() {
        var currentSource = jQuery(this).attr('src');
        jQuery(this).attr('src', imgFile);
      }); // end hover
  }); // end each

  //insert new programming below this line
  jQuery('#gallery a').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var imgPath = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var oldImage = jQuery('#photo img');
    var newiamge = jQuery('<img src= "' +../wp-content/uploads/2019/11/slide1.png + '">');
    //make new image invisible
    newImage.hide();
    //add to the #photo div
    jQuery('#photo').prepend(newImage);
    //fade in new image
    newImage.fadeIn(1000);

    //fade out old image and remove from DOM
    oldImage.fadeOut(1000, function() {
      jQuery(this).remove();
    });


  }); // end click

  jQuery('#gallery a:first').click();
}); // end ready
</script>
```

Comment: So, there are a few issues in your question - not sure if they are on the actual site, so let's try and clear those up. 1. Do you actually have a `_js/meet-the-team.js` file and directory in your child theme? 2) Is the JS above in that `meet-the-team.js` file? 3). If it is, why are you using script tags?

Comment: There are a few issues with your code, like: **1.** Did you include those `<script>` tags here by mistake?; **2.** This is going to throw an error message: `newiamge = jQuery('<img src= "' +../wp-content/uploads/2019/11/slide1.png + '">')`, should be `newiamge = jQuery('<img src= "/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/slide1.png">');` **3.** You're declaring the variable `newiamge`, then a little below you're trying to use `newImage`, etc.

Comment: I don't get any error messages as my code is being ignored but thank you I will change the code as you suggest. To answer questions. I am a novice to WordPress so excuse my ignorance. I have a _js/meet-the-team.js file in public_html. I am not aware of any child theme.  I have tried removing the <script> tags but just puts the code as text in the webpage. If I ca get WordPress to read my JQuery then I can get on and correct any mistakes! All help appreciated

Comment: Your `meet-the-team.js` file needs to be inside your theme directory (eg. `/wp-content/themes/my-current-theme/_js/meet-the-team.js`) for it to be properly enqueued by WordPress.

Comment: This is a much bigger issue than one question can handle, since @DougPitchers is so new to WP (especially since there appears not to be a child theme). I would strongly suggest, in your case, to install this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts/ and then add your jQuery to the footer using this plugin. You do not need to call `jquery.js` at all, since WP already does.

Comment: All help appreciated. i inserted the plugin. No Difference. it is still as if the JQuery is not there. While the jQuery syntax might not be entirely correct I am sure it is close enough that at least something would happen if WP was actually processing it. This is what I am eventually trying to replicate: https://www.flattconsulting.com/meet-the-team/